# Build new string column in DataFrame with MultiIndex columns using format based on new Series and existing column

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a DataFrame with MultiIndex columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({('par1','a'):[1,5],('par1','b'):[2,6],
                       ('par1','c'):[3,7],('par1','d'):[4,8]})
df

par1
    a   b   c   d
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
```

Now I want to insert a new level 1 entry. If that involves an expression with existing columns, I can do it this way:

```
df[('par1','a+c')] = df[('par1','a')] + df[('par1','c')]
df

    par1
    a   b   c   d   a+c
0   1   2   3   4   4
1   5   6   7   8   12
```

Now I have a series `s1` with calculated values (with the same row index as df):

```
s1 = pd.Series([3,7])
```

I want to create a new string column `string`, in which each row is built from element-wise combination of the series and, say, column `('par1','a+c')` **in a `format` statement**.

The only way I found to do this is to first insert Series `s1` as a new column into the table:

```
df[('par1','s1')] = s1
```

then, build the new string with a lambda function by row, using integers as column indices:

```
df[('par1','string')] = df.apply(lambda row: '{} out of {}'.format(row[0],row[4]),axis=1)
```

And finally, drop column `s1`:

```
df.drop(columns='s1',level=1,inplace=True)
df

    par1
    a   b   c   d   a+c   string
0   1   2   3   4   4   1 out of 4
1   5   6   7   8   12  5 out of 12
```

This seems like extremely convoluted. Is there an easier way?

Comment: The series seems to have nothing to do with your output. Some details are not relevant here.

Comment: How about `df[('par1','string')] = df.iloc[:,0].astype(str) + ' out of ' + df.iloc[:,4].astype(str)`?

Comment: You have found a way to simplify my last step for this particular example, but with the limitation that you can't specify a format (e.g., `%3d`). I guess what I am asking is, can this be done without creating and then deleting an intermediate column?